# Usage of build:haddock-arguments option of stack.yaml

Tags: haskell-stack

How do you pass options to `stack haddock` from stack.yaml? I cannot find any clue to correct syntax neither in documentation nor in stack source code.

Documentation describes the following:

`build:
   haddock-arguments: ""`

Naive `haddock-arguments: "--odir=./docs"` fails with type error:

`…failed to parse field 'haddock-arguments': expected HaddockOptsMonoid, encountered String`

I figured out that it expects it to be like:

`build:
  haddock-arguments:
    odir: "./docs"`

However it fails with error `Unrecognized field in HaddockOptsMonoid: odir`.

What is correct syntax of passing arguments from haddock manual to stack via stack.yaml? In my specific case, I want specify custom output directory.

Comment: What's the error message for that type error? In principle that's the right syntax.

Comment: I also had some limited success with the following command: `cd ~/src/path/; stack haddock --haddock-arguments "--odir=$PWD/docs"`. This generates the haddock index file(s) in `~/src/path/docs` but sadly breaks all the links to module docs inside…

Comment: @sjakobi Added type to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the source I figured out that the syntax is

```
build:
  haddock-arguments:
    haddock-args:
    - "--odir=./docs"
```

In a sample project this has the following result (notice the location of the `docs` directory deep down in `.stack-work`):

```
$ ls .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-6.3/7.10.3/doc/docs/ | cat
doc-index.html
frames.html
haddock-util.js
hslogo-16.png
index-frames.html
index.html
minus.gif
ocean.css
plus.gif
synopsis.png
```

The links in `index.html` are broken, so I'm slightly pessimistic that you can achieve what you want by passing arguments to `haddock` in this way.

Comment: It works, thanks. Too bad that haddock in stack as of 1.3.2 is broken in several ways.